# Migrate standalone Solr to Solr Cloud by copying index directory to new empty collection

Tags: solr, solrcloud

We have to migrate customers using Solr to Solr Cloud. I know that the  cleanest way is to re-import data again, but it would last for a really long time.

We tried to create collection in Solr Cloud and then copy there standalone solr indexes. It works.

The question is, whether it is worthy to try this in production. **What can go wrong?**

Comment: Have you seen [Copy existing index from standalone Solr to Solr Cloud](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Copy-existing-index-from-standalone-Solr-to-Solr-cloud-td4149920.html)? As long as you can add replicas after the index has been updated with your old index (and you have the `_version_` field etc. present - i.e. the index works on the same version as your Solr Cloud instance), it seems it should work just fine. The index would be the same files on the disk in the Solr Cloud version as well.

Comment: Its 2014 so something may changed. But what is described there, that`s exactly what we did.. Thanks, still hoping it will not cause any troubles.